# set MaxThreadPoolSize by InitialContext for ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am configuring ActiveMQ via InitialContext similar to this code:

```
try {
    connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
    destination = (Destination)jndiContext.lookup(destinationName);
} catch (NamingException e) {
    LOG.info("JNDI API lookup failed: " + e);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Is it possible to set 
MaxThreadPoolSize via property files?

Here is an example to set it only via code:
http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.html

I cannot find anything useful regarding this topic in the ActiveMQ docs. I saw in sources of ActiveMQConnectionFactory:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.activemq/activemq-core/5.7.0/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java
that the property's name is maxThreadPoolSize. Will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set max pool size using setter method only while creating connection factory. But the value that you pass to setter method that can be read from properties file

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I will have to cast it to ActiveMQConnectionFactory first. This part of the code was quite generic till now..

Comment: If you want to have different attributes value, according to type of connection factory, you will have to do that. generic interface wont be sufficient for specific customization. I don't see any other way.